# Object Orientated Design with Databases and scalability/optimisation using PHP and mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, oop, optimization

I'm currently at an impasse in reguards to the structural design of my website. At the moment I'm using objects to simplify the structure of my site (I have a person object, a party object, a position object, etc...) and in theory each of these is a row from it's respective table in the database.

Now from what I've learnt, OO Design is good for keeping things simple and easy to use/implement, which I agree with - it makes my code look so much cleaner and easier to maintain, but what I'm confused about is how I go about linking my objects to the database.

Let's say there is a person page. I create a person object, which equals one mysql query (which is reasonable), but then that person might have multiple positions which I need to fetch and display on a single page.

What I am currently doing is using a method called *getPositions* from the person object which gets the data from mysql and creates a separate position object for each row, passing in the data as an array. That keeps the queries down to a minimum (2 to a page) but it seems like a horrible implementation and to me, breaks the rules of object orientated design (should I want to change a mysql row, I'd need to change it in multiple places) but the alternative is worse.

In this case the alternative is just getting the ID's that I need and then creating separate positions, passing in the ID which then goes on to getting the row from the database in the constructor. If you have 20 positions per page, it can quickly add up and I've read about how much [Wordpress is criticised](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/behold-wordpress-destroyer-of-cpus.html) for it's high number of queries per page and it's CPU usage. The other thing I'll need to consider in this case is sorting, and doing it this way means I'll need to sort the data using PHP, which surely can't be as efficient as natively doing it in mysql.

Of course, pages will be (and can be) cached, but to me, this seems almost like cheating for poorly built applications. In this case, what is the correct solution?

Answer (score 0):

The way you're doing it now is at least on the right track.  Having an array in the parent object with references to the children is basically how the data is represented in the database.

I'm not completely sure from your question if you're storing the children as references in the parent's array, but you should be and that's how PHP should store them by default.  If you also use a singleton pattern for your objects that are pulled from the database, you should never need to modify multiple objects to change one row as you suggest in your question.

You should probably also create multiple constructors for your objects (using static methods that return new instances) so you can create them from their ID and have them pull the data or just create them from data you already have.  The latter case would be used when you're creating children; you can have the parent pull all of the data for its children and create all of them using only one query.  Getting a child from its ID will probably be used somewhere else so its good just to have if its needed.

For sorting, you could create additional private (or public if you want) arrays that have the children sorted in a particular way with references to the same objects the main array references.